# Pass object back from ionic model service

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a factory for a modal that pulls in an array(list) and I have a `ng-click` where I get the `index` and then get the `object` I want to pass the object back to my controller so I can then use it.

I not sure how I will pass the object back to the controller.

This is the function in my service that fires the `open()` for the modal and I am passing it the model that i receive from a rest call.

```
function CopyModalService($ionicModal, $rootScope) {
var $scope = $rootScope.$new(),
  myModalInstanceOptions = {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  };

return {
  open: open
};

function open(model) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/copy-modal.html',
    myModalInstanceOptions)
    .then(function (modalInstance) {

      $scope.model = model;

      $scope.addCopyCertificate = function(index){
        console.log('click', $scope.model[index]);
      };
      $scope.close = function () {
        closeAndRemove(modalInstance);
      };
      return modalInstance.show(model);
    });

}
```

This is the html in the modal so you can get the picture

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item row" ng-repeat="item in model">
      <span class="col col-67">{{item.installerReference}}</span>
      <span class="col">
      <button class="button button-calm button-calm-search ion-ios-arrow-down"
              ng-click="addCopyCertificate($index)"></button>
    </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

When I click the button in the html `addCopyCertificate()` it all appears fine but how do I pass that back to the controller.

In my controller I am using it like this: (which is working)

```
if (res.length) {
        CopyModalService.open(res);
      }else{
        Alert.showAlert('No matching certificates');
       ....
      }
```

Comment: have you tried to set a return in your close method? return of the object you need...and in plus..there's  amode in ionic modal to pass data to controller calling it with promise (then(function(res){})

Comment: try to see this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-from-parent-controller-to-ionicmodal/2030/6

Comment: I want it to return when I click the `addCopyCertificate` I don't want it to happen on close, I have looked in the console and looked at $scope but can't suss it out

Comment: what if try to set $scope.addCopyCertificate = function(index){
        console.log('click', $scope.model[index]); return  $scope.model[index];
      };

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I can see the object but I don't know how I will get it back to the controller. So after I have called `CopyModalService.open(res);` I need a way to then send the object back to the controller ?? wehn I click the addCopyCertificate If I return the object then I need to pass it to a function and then to the controller, I have tried many ways and can't seem to do it. I need some method to hook into somehow, then what do I put in the controller to get the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about `$rootScope.$broadcast`? something like:

```
function CopyModalService($ionicModal, $rootScope) {
var $scope = $rootScope.$new(),
  myModalInstanceOptions = {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  };

return {
  open: open
};

function open(model) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/copy-modal.html',
    myModalInstanceOptions)
    .then(function (modalInstance) {

      $scope.model = model;

      $scope.addCopyCertificate = function(index){
        console.log('click', $scope.model[index]);
$rootScope.$broadcast('update-controller',$scope.model[index]);
      };
      $scope.close = function () {
        closeAndRemove(modalInstance);
      };
      return modalInstance.show(model);
    });

}
```

and then when you want to get the value ..attach the listener with `$rootScope.$on('')` (or better `$scope.$on()`) ..something like

```
if (res.length) {
        CopyModalService.open(res);
$scope.$on('update-controller',function(event, data){
console.log(data);
});
      }else{
        Alert.showAlert('No matching certificates');
       ....
      }
```

Comment: On this line `$scope.$on('update-controller',function(data){` you have to pass `$scope.$on('update-controller',function(event, data){` then your data is the object.. Thank you, I have learnt about `$on` and `$broadcast`